# CodeDeploy AfterInstall logs

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I'm having trouble with the AfterInstall hook for CodeDeploy. My code appears to be deploying, however I the AfterInstall script doesn't appear to be running. I have create a file in `data/afterinstall.sh` and I set the appspec.yml to execute it

```
Hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: data/afterinstall.sh
      timeout: 500
```

My afterinstall script is basic:

```
cd /final_path
touch test.txt
```

No file is being created. CodeDeploy succeeds. If I make the script return false, the step still succeeds and if I provide a location that doesn't exist, it still succeeds.

Where can I get more detailed output or logs for the afterinstall step?

This doesn't appear to contain any useful logs: `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log`.

`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log` appears to be empty

Answer (score 2):

As per the [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html), there are two places to look for logs:

1. `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log`
2. `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`

The first is the most useful and should log any errors in your `AfterInstall` script. Just look for the lines  `LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall`.

In your case it's most likely a permission issue. Does the user running the `AfterInstall` script have permission to write to the `/final_path` directory?

If not, then you need to set the `runas` property in your `appspec.yml` file. For example if your web root is owned by ubuntu or ec2-user then run the script as them:

```
AfterInstall:
    - location: data/afterinstall.sh
      timeout: 500
      runas: ubuntu
```